# Youtube video loading porblem!

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, 64-bit

Ok so yeah as the title say's my youtube vids wont load.I do have java installed, and this is for the 64-bit version of Ubuntu btw the version is 12.10, TO be even more specific the video just dosent load all the way, it wont load at all! It just say's a error has occurred Any opinion's?

Comment: Firefox or Chrome Browser, Java has noting to do with youtube videos playing, although Javascript disabled can cause videos not to play.

Answer (score 1):

It's advisable to install FLASH from Adobe on your system for watching YT-video's.

Open the softwarecenter and typ in the search-field: **restricted extra's**
install the pack for Ubuntu (not Xubuntu or Kubuntu !!) this will deliver you automatically the desired FLASH-player.

Updates for FLASH come with the updatemanager, so no worry's there. Only updates , not new versions of Flash since Adobe stopped making new versions for Linux in general. (doesn't matter, all YouTube video's work fine with this version Adobe releases)

JAVA is not used for watching YouTube-video's, so there you are wrong.

Some YouTube video's however come already in HTML5, what is to become the new standard.

Succes !

You can also install Chromium from the softwarecenter, if desired.

Comment: I already have the Restricted extra's installed, as well as Adobe Flash (witch i couldnt find in the software center so i got it from there website) So yeah.. Any other suggestion's Lol Believe me i tried everything google search could offer!